# Why do I get this code 139 error (signal 11: SIGSEGV), and what can I do about it?

Tags: runtime-error, macos-catalina, exit-code

I've recently upgraded to Mac OS Catalina and my project that I have been working on keeps getting interrupted by this new error before any of the main code runs:

> Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)

I believe that this occurs because of one package I'm using, the [Python Arcade package](http://arcade.academy/). I do not get this error whenever I comment out the "import arcade" line. I have tried the [solution suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49414841/process-finished-with-exit-code-139-interrupted-by-signal-11-sigsegv) that I should try to diagnose it with gdb, but I cannot get gdb to work correctly.  Does anyone have any other suggestions for why this might be happening?  I reinstalled anaconda and all the relevant packages after hearing that there were complications with the new catalina update, that didn't resolve it either.

I'm running out of options and I have to get my code working as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I Fixed the Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV) error

the problem is with import cv2. you need to use pip install numpy==1.24.3

this version of numpy fixed it. the newest version of numpy must be broken